# New eslint errors with the @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-* rules

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm having some trouble with adding them into some existing projects. For example, I have a class in a module that I developed:

```js
export default class ClassName {
  // Class members
}
```

Now I import that into another project:

```js
import ClassName from 'modulename';

const object = new ClassName();
```

I get 2 errors on this line.

On the `object` in `const object`:

```
error  Unsafe assignment of an any value                @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
```

On the `new` in `new ClassName`:

```
error  Unsafe construction of an any type value         @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
```

How can I avoid these errors?! I would really like to be able to follow these rules because I think they'd be so useful!

Thanks.

---

Here's another example:

```js
import { readJsonSync } from 'fs-extra';
const testEnv = readJsonSync(testEnvPath);
```

Here I get the `no-unsafe-assignment` error on the `testEnv` of `const testEnv`, and the `no-unsafe-call` error on the `readJsonSync` call on the second line.

I can get rid of the first one with this code:

```js
interface ITestEnv {
  // interface members
}
const testEnv: ITestEnv = readJsonSync(testEnvPath) as ITestEnv;
```

however, I still can't figure out how to get rid of the second one on the `readJsonSync` call.

Comment: I faced a similar issue. My thoughts to use javascript for my projects since typescript brings a lot of pain

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

ESlint can not resolve the absolute import of your module,
which makes it to infer your class type as `any`.

Make sure `baseUrl` and `paths` in *tsconfig.json* file used by ESlint are defined correctly.

@see [Typescript – Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html)

Comment: it didn't help me :(

Comment: If you are using types from definitely typed repo, make sure to add the type to your tsconfi.json, e.g.:
`"compilerOptions": { "types": [ "json2csv" ] }`

Comment: If I'm using `baseUrl` and `paths` in such a way that `tsc` transpiles the code without issue and the resulting Javascript can be run without errors, how is it that ESLint cannot resolve the import?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you have just one error coming from the constructor, which is cascading to the const assignment. Something in your class implementation is making the type-inference to be inferred as `any`.

Not saying your code is incorrect. It might be, but there's an ([open issue on Github](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2109)) reporting a constructor as being incorrectly flagged by the same rule.

On your second issue, have you added [@type/fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/fs-extra) as a project dependency? Many npm packages do not have types themselves. Types are created by someone and added to the **@types library**. When that's the case, the `@types/package_name` must be added as a dependency separately.

Comment: Indeed, I had that thought and added the `@types/fs-extra` module as a dependency; it didn't help. And a thought on that: surely there are modules out there without the types defined, either in the module or in the `@types` family...so what would we do then? Would this eslint rule stop us from using that module in a typescript project?!

Comment: If types are not available, we can always write our own interfaces and types and use them. We must have types if we want the compiler to do its job and check everything. But of course situations may arise when we may want to edit a rule to generate warnings, instead of errors. Type checking is a trade off: we loose convenience in exchange for safety. But in the end it’s the team or developer who decides which rules eslint should enforce.

Comment: Why did you use sentence "Something in your class implementation is making the type-inference to be inferred as any."  in part of Something?... What exactly make it happen? This sentence reads a bit smeared in my opinion.